# Функция выдает ошибку из-за неправильного отступа, хотя с ними все правильно

Tags: python, pandas, csv, обработка-данных

Есть 2 csv файла. 1 с фильмами, второй с тем какие оценки поставили пользователи фильмам. Общие поля movieId.
Первая функция считает и выдает среднюю оценку фильма опираясь на "movieId".
Вторая создает колонку и добавляет в нее данные которые посчитала 1 функция.
после выводится первый файл к которому добавляется новая колонка.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import math
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from collections import defaultdict


df = pd.read_csv('файл1', encoding='latin-1')
df1 = pd.read_csv('файл2', encoding='latin-1')

#ПОДСЧЕТ СРЕДНЕЙ ОЦЕНКИ ФИЛЬМА
def fmedR(i):
    gcount = float(0)#общее количество оценок
    count = float(0)#сума оценок
    with open('файл2')as df1:
        read1 = csv.DictReader(df1, delimiter=",")
        for row in read1:
            if float (row['movieId']) == i:# і - ето заданый индетификатор фильма
                gcount += 1
                count += float(row['rating'])
    if gcount == 0:
        rta = "No data"
    else:
        rta = count/gcount
        rta = round(rta,2)
    return rta     

def get_medR(data):
    medR = [] # делаем новую колонку
    for i in range (0, data.shape[0]):
        medR.append(fmedR(data['movieId'][i]))#наполняем ее
    return medR

df['medR'] = get_medR(df)
df.head(4)
```

Проблема в следующем:

1. Доходя до выполнения `with open('файл2')as df1:` функция начинает ругаться из-за неправильного отступа(с ним все правильно), хотя когда данный код был сам по себе он прекрасно все считал.
2. В случае удаления данной строки выдает следующую ошибку

```
>>> df['medR'] = get_medR(df)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in get_medR
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in fmedR
KeyError: 'movieId'
```

Скорее всего проблема в строке `medR.append(fmedR(data['movieId'][i]))`, где я ввожу данные которые будет обрабатывать первая функция.

Каким образом мне можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: И всё же проверьте в той строке может у вас там помесь табуляций с пробелами. Уберите вообще отступ там, а потом сделайте отступ заново.

Comment: делал уже, не помогло(

Comment: Значит, в предыдущих строках ещё проверьте отступы

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в строке medR.append(fmedR(data['movieId'][i])), где я ввожу данные которые будет обрабатывать первая функция

Comment: @ВизардВалимар, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать модуль Pandas по назначению. Т.е. если вы пытаетесь написать цикл, а тем более несколько циклов при использовании Pandas - это значит что скорее всего вы что-то делаете не так.

```
df = pd.read_csv('файл1', encoding='latin-1')
df1 = pd.read_csv('файл2', encoding='latin-1')

df["medR"] = df["movieId"].map(df1.groupby("movieId")["rating"].mean().round(2))
```

Это должно заменить весь ваш код и функции...

PS данный код не тестировался по причине отстутствия в вопросе [минимального, самодостаточного и **воспроизводимого** примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).